# To do list software with collapse, coloring and endless nesting

Tags: cloud-service, color, todo

Current I am using Notepad++ with custom syntax highlighting to have a to do list which supports the following:

- Nesting
- Collapsing scopes
- Colors to indicate status
- Clickable URLs

It works pretty well. I like it for the way that I can quickly create an overview. Of course with this freedom it is required to be consistent, but so you have to with a word document for instance.

So it works, but I would prefer something like this in the cloud, which can easily be shared with others and is multiplatform (so I have the same list in my mobile phone). Trello is nice with all fancy features, but I'm missing the endless hierarchy and scope collapsing. I do not need to add checkboxes, pictures and attachments. And online Google Docs doesn't suit my needs because it has no automatic syntax highlighting, adding the colors myself slows down the creation of the list tremendously.

Is there any software that meets my needs of this freedom, hierarchy, collapsing and in the cloud?

[image]

If you are interested, here is the syntax definition for Notepad++, go to Menu -> Language -> Define ... -> Import.

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <UserLang name="ToDo" ext="" udlVersion="2.1">
        <Settings>
            <Global caseIgnored="no" allowFoldOfComments="no" foldCompact="no" forcePureLC="0" decimalSeparator="0" />
            <Prefix Keywords1="yes" Keywords2="yes" Keywords3="yes" Keywords4="no" Keywords5="yes" Keywords6="no" Keywords7="no" Keywords8="yes" />
        </Settings>
        <KeywordLists>
            <Keywords name="Comments">00 01 02 03/* 04*/</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, extras1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, extras2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, range"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Operators1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Operators2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, open">{</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, close">}</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, open"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, close"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, open"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, close"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords1">#</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords2">-</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords3">@&#x000D;&#x000A;FILE:&#x000D;&#x000A;FUNC:&#x000D;&#x000A;file:&#x000D;&#x000A;func:</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords4">%</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords5">!</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords6">*</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords7">?</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords8">Q:&#x000D;&#x000A;</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Delimiters"></Keywords>
        </KeywordLists>
        <Styles>
            <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENTS" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="LINE COMMENTS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="NUMBERS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS1" fgColor="000040" bgColor="0080FF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS2" fgColor="004040" bgColor="EAC266" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="00FFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFF00" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS5" fgColor="400000" bgColor="FF0000" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="00FF40" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS7" fgColor="FFFF00" bgColor="400000" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS8" fgColor="FF8000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="OPERATORS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE1" fgColor="000000" bgColor="C0C0C0" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN COMMENT" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS1" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        </Styles>
    </UserLang>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Comment: What OS/platform? Or do you want cloud-based apps only? Clarify to make your minimum requirements more obvious.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes cloud based is min. req. for it to make a significant difference from using Notepad++ for me.

Comment: Have a look at mind mapping software, for a different view at such kind of documents.